# How to choose a custom node version for Azure WebJobs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I'm working on a website that deploys its custom version of node (x64) that we upload and configure via iisnode.yml. We have a dependency in a binary package (zopfli) that we build locally and deploy as well. So far so good.
The problem is with one of the webjobs we have. It seems like it is always using the x86 version of the node version set in WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION no matter the value of issnode.yml or the platform I select via the portal.

So my question is:

How can I tell my webjobs to use the same version I specify in iisnode.yml (bin\node.exe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebJob won't look at iisnode.yml. The simplest solution is to create a run.cmd file in your WebJobs folder, and have it explicitly run what you want. e.g. it could have:

```
bin\node.exe foo.js
```

Comment: We had to do a bit more to get the right exit code and also get the right dependencies because console jobs seem to be copied somewhere else but this put us in the right path. Our run.ps1 file looks like this:

`cd D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\App_data\\myjob\\
D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\bin\\node.exe index.js exit $LASTEXITCODE;
`